# D7 - How to get mlid value from path of menu item

Tags: routes, uri

Quick question. How to get mlid value from path of menu item. There is a function called menu_link_load() but it requires an mlid value, but I need something exacly the same function using path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no build-in function for this. You can use menu_tree_all_data(), but it returns all the menu. After that you can compare in loops your path with the paths returend. But there is a better and easier answer. Here it is:

```
$mlid = array();
$q = 'your-path';
$menu_info = db_select('menu_links' , 'ml')
  ->condition('ml.link_path' , $q)
  ->fields('ml', array('mlid', 'plid'))
  ->execute()
  ->fetchAll();

foreach($menu_info as $key => $value) {
  $mlid[] = $menu_info[$key]->mlid;
}
```

Comment: Yes. Using a db query is the correct solution. One thing to note is that there can be more than one menu link for a given path.

Comment: you're right about this number of results

Answer (score -2):

Try using [menu_get_item()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_item/7), this should load your menu item directly from your path.

Comment: No, I've already tried it. It returns info about the page that the menu item corresponds to. But I've already found the answer.